# Video streaming and compression using Raspberry pi

Tags: video, streaming

I want to stream video and audio using raspberry pi. Raspberry pi-1 should act as video streaming server  while other arduinos should as as forwarder. Destination node will be again raspberry pi -2. I am also doing video encoding/compression on received video before sending  stream and decompression at receiver side. 
Can I get similar implementation anywhere?

i am  doing  reasearch  on video streaming in wireless sensor network ( Ad Hoc Network )  .  By using motion , raspitill  ,  raspberry pi became video streaming server . Before delivery of stream , i have to first compress images and combine using commands :

raspistill -o myimage_%04d.jpg -tl 60000 -t 7200000

and

avconv -r 10 -i myimage_%04d.jpg 
       -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -g 15
       timelapse.mp4

**Can i compress these images using my compression algorithm  by storing it in some python script .**

I installed DHCP server  and apache web server on Raspberry pi to make it ad-hoc router cum  web server . So user can join it easily and  do surf through websites inside it  and i want to stream  compressed videos to user  inside its wifi  hot spot.

Comment: Are you have a specific problem with your code? If not, this may not be the right forum for this question.

Comment: I do not know how to compress and stream video . i got info regarding raspivid , gstreamer but can they do compression and streaming . If no , which are other alternative ?  Did you get what was my my question ?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for software. You may want to check out [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: `avconv` is already compressing your images. If you just put your `timelapse.mp4` files into the Apache web root then they would be available to anyone on the network via a web browser. I'm not sure what you would need a python script for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to set a multi camera sensors / controller centralized ? .. I just delivered that last week ..

tracks :
capture the pi cam stream using raspivid and convert to flv stream on the local host using nginx rtmp module (nginx is my prefered lightweight http/ rtmp server).
On the controller side use ffmpeg to split the device stream into jpeg image and then rebuild a new mpeg video with mjpg-streamer that publish on an Ip port available for web appliaction (src tag with image address just work fine) . You can also connect to the device in rtmp mode .. but that costs ..

this solution tested on a raw wifi connection provides a < 0.3s latency streaming on the web server side ( with multiple  video panes)  .. really ^^.
Note that the splitted incoming stream as jpeg image in a cache directory  fits perfectly with motion detection tool needs ^^

the "compression" is assumed by the nginx server (gzip option) .. but I don't think it could be efficient with a video stream ..  rtmp protocol is perhaps as jpeg already compressed ? to google ^^

for this kind of architecture , try to provide a sepcific and dedicated wifi network to guarantee bandwith needs